# Get documents with at least two values for a especific condition in an Array, Query in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-compass

Suppose that you have a collection in [this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHkTx.jpg).

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f21a77c52efa009cc9857a7"), "results" : [ 76, 72, 93 ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f21a993b4d13477dd950904"), "results" : [ 90, 94, 80 ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f21a9a0b4d13477dd950905"), "results" : [ 70, 73, 99 ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f21a9abb4d13477dd950906"), "results" : [ 91, 85, 99 ] }
```

I am using Mongodb compass.

I would like to find the documents that their `results` array contain at least two items greater than 90.

I've tried doing this:

```
{$or:[{$and:[ {"results.0": { $gte : 90 } },{"results.1": { $gte : 90 } } ]}, {$and: [ {"results.1": { $gte : 90 } },{"results.2": { $gte : 90 } } ]}, {$and: [ {"results.0": { $gte : 90 } },{"results.2": { $gte : 90 } } ]}]}
```

With this query I get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAoMh.jpg)

I would like to know if there is "an optimized query" for doing the same thing!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the array to contain only matching items and then check it's size:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmp: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$results",
          as: "res",
          cond: {
            $gte: [
              "$$res",
              90
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "tmp.1": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tmp: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n2OfQgXUbaX)